# Swapping Dynamic allocated structures

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to swap two structures which are dynamically allocated. But only string(name) is swapping. Anyone can tell me what's wrong with my snippet.

```
typedef struct
{
char name[20];
int num;
char ch;
}student;

void swap(student **a,student **b)
{
        student *temp;
        temp = *a;
        *a = *b;
        *b = temp;

}

void main()
{

        student *s;
        int i;
        s = (student *)malloc(10 * sizeof(student));

        printf("enter values: ");

        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
                scanf("%d %c %s",&s[i].num,&s[i].ch,s[i].name);

        swap(s+3,s+4);

        printf("\n");
        for(i=0;i<10;i++)
                printf("%d %c %s\n",s[i].num,s[i].ch,s[i].name);


        printf("\n");
}
```

'

Comment: Each structure is not dynamically allocated independently. You're trying to swap two structures that are in a *single* dynamically allocated sequence of structures. You're not going to do that by swapping pointers. There is only one mutable pointer in this: `s` in `main()`.

Comment: Lose one level of indirection on *every* pointer in your `swap` function. The two params should be `student *`, and `temp` should not be a pointer at all. The rest can stay the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `swap()` gets two parameters of type `student **`.
However, in the call `swap(s+3,s+4);`, you pass it two arguments of type `student *` -- as is the type of `s`. Could you compile it at all?

Anyway, what you are doing in the `swap()` function is replacing the content to which *each pointer is pointing*. That is, if you have had two pointers to students (say: p1, that is pointing to student s1, and p2, that is pointing to student s2), you could have called `swap(&p1, &p2)` and have them point to the other students (i.e., p1 to s2 and p2 to s1).

But in your `main()`'s code, you are not dealing with pointers to `student`s. Rather, you try to replace the content of the students themselves -- which is not what `swap()` does at all.

Comment: compiled and no error. only name is swapping between structures instead of whole structure.

I tried passing Addresses swap(&s[3],&s[4]), But still only name is swapping not the whole structure

Comment: Addresses swap will only work if you used pointers. Please read the revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

The are an erron, the pointer refers to same memory location , Try use another student pointer for example declare another student *s2!!!